# three js can't load fbx function error 'loader.setRequestHeader is not a function'

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, frontend

I'm trying to load my model in fbx format but getting error code below (obj loader and mtl loader is working without problem but only fbx loader gives error)

**ERROR**

```
Uncaught TypeError: loader.setRequestHeader is not a function
    at FBXLoader.load (FBXLoader.js:38)
    at init (earthie.js:444)
    at EarthF (earthie.js:413)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (earthie.js:45)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

**HTML SCRIPTS**

```
    <script src="_3rdparty/three.js/DDSLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="_3rdparty/three.js/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="_3rdparty/three.js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="_3rdparty/three.js/FBXLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="_3rdparty/three.js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="earthie.js"></script>
```

**EARTHIE.JS**

```
const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
        
            loader.load( '_models/devilskullson.fbx', function ( object ) {

                scene.add( object );

            } );
```

Comment: Make sure, that all scripts/modules belong to the same version/revision of Three.js.